# Export subfolder from the package

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a Typescript package

```
package.json
src/
  index.ts
  common/
    index.ts
  sub/
    index.ts
```

I want to be able to:

```
import {...} from '<package>';
import {...} from '<package>/sub';
```

But not for `<package>/common`

Is that possible to do that without custom declaration files?

My `package.json` looks based on [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079):

```
"exports": {
  ".": "./dist/index.js",
  "./common": "./dist/common/index.js"
},
"typesVersions": {
  "*": {
    "common": ["declarations/common/index.d.ts"]
  }
}
```

With this approach, I don't have any issues with the Typescript part. But once I'm trying to build it, it fails with JS:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<package>/sub' in '...'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not entirely sure why this works, but this block in my `package.json` worked for me:

```
{
    // ...
    "files": [
        "/dist"
    ],
    "main": "./dist/index.js",
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "exports": {
        ".": "./dist/index.js",
        "./types": "./dist/types/index.js",
        "./generate": "./dist/generate/index.js"
    },
    "typesVersions": {
        "*": {
            "types": [
                "./dist/types/index.d.ts"
            ],
            "generate": [
                "./dist/generate/index.d.ts"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "ESNext"
    }
}
```

And this is my file structure:

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
dist/ // and all its subfolders
src/
  generate/
    index.ts
  types/
    index.ts
  index.ts
```